# Xcode 5.0 .xib file? Where is it?

Tags: xcode, xib, xcode5

This is probably an easy question. I am just starting to use Xcode 5.0 and can't find the .xib (interface builder) file when I create a new iOS application for Ipad. I am very new at this and have looked it up. I have found that maybe the Main.Storyboard is it but can't be sure.

Any suggestions?

Sorry if this is too easy of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards have "replaced" xibs.

You can still use xibs in your project, but by default storyboards are used.